# Can a US permanent resident return to USA after a 50-day visit to Mexico?

Tags: usa, us-residents

I'm leaving USA, where I am a permanent resident, for 50 days this summer to go to Mexico. People have told me that if you leave USA you can't come back.

Can I still come back?

Comment: Where were you born, and what is your citizenship?

Comment: @KateGregory I do not believe that the traveler's citizenship matters, because she is a permanent resident of the US.

Comment: Wish that would be so, but last week PRs born in the 7 countries were not allowed back if they left. That could happen again and if I was in that situation I would not leave, just in case.

Comment: Did you review [International Travel as a Permanent Resident](https://www.uscis.gov/green-card/after-green-card-granted/international-travel-permanent-resident)?

Comment: @pnuts I don't see how an unlawful resident of the US can reasonably claim that their residency is permanent.  Although *lawful permanent resident* us the usual phrase in government use, most people recognize that *lawful* is superfluous in that phrase, and normally speak of *permanent resident* in colloquial use.

Answer (score 2):

From [International Travel as a Permanent Resident](https://www.uscis.gov/green-card/after-green-card-granted/international-travel-permanent-resident):

> **Does travel outside the United States affect my permanent resident status?**
>
> Permanent residents are free to travel outside the United States, and temporary or brief travel usually does not affect your permanent resident status. If it is determined, however, that you did not intend to make the United States your permanent home, you will be found to have abandoned your permanent resident status.  A general guide used is whether you have been absent from the United States for more than a year. Abandonment may be found to occur in trips of less than a year where it is believed you did not intend to make the United States your permanent residence.  While brief trips abroad generally are not problematic, the officer may consider criteria such as whether your intention was to visit abroad only temporarily, whether you maintained U.S. family and community ties, maintained U.S employment, filed U.S. income taxes as a resident, or otherwise established your intention to return to the United States as your permanent home. Other factors that may be considered include whether you maintained a U.S. mailing address, kept U.S. bank accounts and a valid U.S. driver’s license, own property or run a business in the United States, or any other evidence that supports the temporary nature of your absence.

In short, a 50 day trip outside the country is fine.